# -p in shell command

Tags: shell

I have come across a shell command wherein the author has used -p switch.
The command is exactly like this.

```
$ read -p "press enter" fakeEnterKey
```

I tried with and without `-p`. When `-p` is not used it doesn't print some warning.
I would like to know what exactly this switch is doing?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: I don't think the `-p` option is defined by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html). What shell is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your shell.

If you use `bash`, then `read -p prompt ...` will output the prompt text before reading. Note that this is not necessarily a warning. It can be arbitrary informational text.

If you use `zsh`, then `read -p` will read from a co-process instead of stdout.

If you use another shell, you should consult the shell's manual.